# Display table cell in a scrollview and scroll to the next or previous in swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, tableview, tablecell

I have a table view with cells, when I select a cell it displays in another view and shows detailed information. Rather than using swipe gesture, how can I  lazy load 3 details cells in a scrollView when the scrollview scrolls. ScrollView scrolling is more seamless.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: @Luzo, I just edited the question. The question is loading each cell detail information as a page in a scrollview. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, still no. Did you have a problem that after the selection only one detail is displayed? Or that you don't know how to do infinite scroll?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Horizontal UICollectionView to display your cells details, you need to pass the entire array of elements to your new details viewcontroller and then scroll the collectionview to the indexpath selected.

here you can find an example of how to create a Horizontal UICollectionview

https://medium.com/@shaibalassiano/tutorial-horizontal-uicollectionview-with-paging-9421b479ee94